# Hangfire jobs don't run at time of day

Tags: c#, cron, hangfire

I got [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) working with various-minute intervals. (The timing of the initial job seems a bit random, but then works great thereafter.)

However, my time-of-day jobs are not firing at all.

```cs
using var server = new BackgroundJobServer();

Console.WriteLine("Hangfire Server started. Press any key to exit...");
Console.WriteLine($"Started: {DateTime.Now:g}");
Console.WriteLine();

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<TaskExecutor>("X", x => x.RunTask("One Time 1"), "0 10 8 8 */1");
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<TaskExecutor>("Z", x => x.RunTask("One Time 2"), "0 10 * * * ");

Console.ReadKey();
```

I was expecting both tasks to run at 10:00 AM today (8/8/2023). But neither one runs.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

*Note: My `TaskExecutor.RunTask()` method is not shown. But I'm sure it is right because it worked fine for various minute intervals.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Hangfire uses UTC time by default. The code works as expected by using local time.

```cs
RecurringJobOptions jobOptions = new()
{
    TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local
};

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<TaskExecutor>("X", x => x.RunTask("One Time 1"), "0 10 8 8 */1", jobOptions);
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<TaskExecutor>("Z", x => x.RunTask("One Time 2"), "0 10 * * * ", jobOptions);
```